# How to retrieve double values from entity inside list and deal with them

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I didn't know how to create a better title so here is a full explanation.

I have `wallet` entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "wallet")
public class Wallet {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "wallet_id")
private Long id;

@NotBlank(message = "Please, insert a wallet name")
private String walletName;

@NotNull(message = "Please, insert a amount")
private Double initialBalance;

@Transient
private double totalBalance;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false, referencedColumnName = "user_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
@JsonIgnore
private User user;

@Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
private Long userId;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "wallet", cascade = {
        CascadeType.ALL})
private Set<Transaction> transactions;
```

And I also have a `transaction` entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "transaction")
public class Transaction {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "transaction_id")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
private Long userId;

@Column(name = "wallet_name", nullable = false)
private String walletName;

@Column
@NotNull(message = "Please, insert a amount")
@Min(value = 0, message = "Please, insert a positive amount")
private Double amount;

@Column
private String note;

@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
@Column(name = "date")
private LocalDate date;

@ManyToOne
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.NO_ACTION)
@JoinColumn(name = "wallet_id", nullable = false)
private Wallet wallet;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "transaction_type", columnDefinition = "ENUM('EXPENSE', 'INCOME')")
private TransactionType transactionType;

@Nullable
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "expense_categories", columnDefinition = "ENUM('FOOD_AND_DRINK', 'SHOPPING', 'TRANSPORT', 'HOME'," +
        " 'BILLS_AND_FEES', 'ENTERTAINMENT', 'CAR', 'TRAVEL', 'FAMILY_AND_PERSONAL', 'HEALTHCARE'," +
        " 'EDUCATION', 'GROCERIES', 'GIFTS', 'BEAUTY', 'WORK', 'SPORTS_AND_HOBBIES', 'OTHER')")
private ExpenseCategories expenseCategories;

@Nullable
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "income_categories", columnDefinition = "ENUM('SALARY', 'BUSINESS', 'GIFTS', 'EXTRA_INCOME', 'LOAN', 'PARENTAL_LEAVE', 'INSURANCE_PAYOUT', 'OTHER')")
private IncomeCategories incomeCategories;
```

Now, for you to get a better picture what I want, I will go chronologically how things work:

Here is controller that allow user to create a `income transaction:`

```
@PostMapping("/saveIncome/{walletId}")
public String saveIncome(@PathVariable(value = "walletId") long walletId, @Valid Transaction transaction, BindingResult result, Model model) {

    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    UserDetailsImpl user = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();
    long userId = user.getId();

    Wallet wallet = walletService.getWalletById(walletId);

    boolean thereAreErrors = result.hasErrors();
    if (thereAreErrors) {
        model.addAttribute("incomeCategories", IncomeCategories.values());
        return "income_transaction";
    }

    transaction.setWallet(wallet);
    transaction.setUserId(userId);
    transaction.setWalletName(wallet.getWalletName());
    transactionService.saveIncome(transaction, walletId, userId);
    return "redirect:/api/wallet/userWallet/balance/" + userId;
}
```

Nothing special, and that works fine.

Now, when a user successfully created a transaction, I have a controller that returns a page where the user actually can see all transactions that he made. This is how its looks:

```
@GetMapping("/userTransactions/{user_id}")
public String getUserTransactions(@PathVariable("user_id") long user_id, TransactionGroup transactionGroup, Model model) {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    UserDetailsImpl user = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();
    long userId = user.getId();
    model.addAttribute("userId", userId);

    List<Transaction> transactions = transactionRepository.getTransactionsByUserId(user_id);
    List<TransactionGroup> transactionByDate = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Transaction> transOnSingleDate = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean currDates = transactions.stream().findFirst().isPresent();

    if (currDates) {
        LocalDate currDate = transactions.get(0).getDate();

        TransactionGroup transGroup = new TransactionGroup();

        for (Transaction t : transactions) {
            if (!currDate.isEqual(t.getDate())) {
                transGroup.setDate(currDate);
                transGroup.setTransactions(transOnSingleDate);
                transactionByDate.add(transGroup);
                transGroup = new TransactionGroup();
                transOnSingleDate = new ArrayList<>();
            }

            transOnSingleDate.add(t);
            currDate = t.getDate();
        }
        transGroup.setDate(currDate);
        transGroup.setTransactions(transOnSingleDate);

        transactionByDate.add(transGroup);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Empty");
    }


    model.addAttribute("transactionGroup", transactionByDate);
    return "transactions";
}
```

You can see that I have some lists because I wanted to show all transactions by each date. And that also works fine. For more context, this is my 'helper' class that help me to display user transactions by date:

```
public class TransactionGroup {
    private LocalDate date;
    private List<Transaction> transactions;

    public LocalDate getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(LocalDate date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public List<Transaction> getTransactions() {
        return transactions;
    }

    public void setTransactions(List<Transaction> transactions) {
        this.transactions = transactions;
    }
```

Now, I hope you get a full picture of how it works. And now, what do I want to achieve?

You can see here this field:

```
@Column
@NotNull(message = "Please, insert a amount")
@Min(value = 0, message = "Please, insert a positive amount")
private Double amount;
```

I want to calculate amount that left for each date. For example:

`Date 03/03/2023 Transaction income: 100, Transaction income: 100 - Transaction expense: 50 == 150`

I tried like this inside `getUserTransactionController`:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < transGroup.getTransactions().size(); i++) {
            double result = 0;

            if (transGroup.getTransactions().get(i).getTransactionType().getDisplayName().equalsIgnoreCase("income")) {
                System.out.println("Income amount for date " +
                        transGroup.getTransactions().get(i).getDate() + " is " + transGroup.getTransactions().get(i).getAmount());
                result = result + transGroup.getTransactions().get(i).getAmount();
                System.out.println("Result is " + result);
                System.out.println("------");

            }
```

But that isn't good, first of all it return me a correct values but doesnt sum it, and If I even made it so code actually sum it, I dont know how I'm suppose to subtract it from `expense` amount.

Any suggestion, advice, what I can try?

Answer (score 0):

Since you already aggregated all the transactions by each date, It likes a pure calculation issue.

```
LocalDate date = transGroup.getDate();
List<Transaction> transactions = transGroup.getTransactions();
// 1. sum all income
double income = transactions.stream()
        .filter(trans->trans.getTransactionType().getDisplayName().equalsIgnoreCase("income"))
        .mapToDouble(Transaction::getAmount)
        .sum();
// 2. sum all expense
double expense = transactions.stream()
        .filter(trans->trans.getTransactionType().getDisplayName().equalsIgnoreCase("expense"))
        .mapToDouble(Transaction::getAmount)
        .sum();
// 3. subtraction
double left = income - expense;
System.out.println("date:" + date + ",income:" + income + ",expense:"+ expense + ",left:" + left);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already have this, its like mine example just you are using filter, your example is calculating balance just for one date like mine, while other dates are not calculated

Comment: Sorry, I now saw that you are answering to my previous question, I managed to solve this like u, check my new question here. Its connected with this one, and my comment answer is actually a problem that now occurs and that is explained in new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75627793/for-loop-doesnt-loop-through-all-data-from-table

Comment: for other dates, you can wrap this code with  for loop `List<TransactionGroup>` condition in the outside.